# Bluetooth headphones button event detection in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, browser, bluetooth, dom-events

I am building a web app where I detect the headphones button event. I succeeded in capturing headphones button event when they are plugged in. Now I am trying to capture Bluetooth headphones next button event. Any help on this please?

Code for headphone button detection.

```
 document.addEventListener('volumeupbutton', () => {
   //Do something here
 }, false);
```

I need something similar to this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `keydown and keyup` events for implementing the long press functionality.

```js
// Imprementation of Long Press

const longPressTime = 1500;
let keyDownTimeout;
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (keyDownTimeout) {
    return;
  }
  keyDownTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    // button was held for 1500ms, consider it a long-press
    if (e.code === 'ArrowUp') {
      console.log("Action Performed");
      // do long-press action
    } else {
      console.log("Other action performed");
    }
  }, longPressTime);
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  clearTimeout(keyDownTimeout);
  keyDownTimeout = 0;
});
```

```html
Press any key
```

The above methods work for single key long press. Refer to [KeyCode](https://keycode.info/) for key code. 
[Demo of above](https://codepen.io/akansh/pen/aeEqRW)

Comment: It's an alternative, but does not answer to the original question.

Comment: My answer was aimed at the original question. You commented on my answer and I addressed your comments with edits and responses, I'm not sure why you reworked my code as a new answer (which was more of a long-press example than an answer to the question).

Comment: @NickGagne I figured it out that the code had another flaw. The keydown event is listened multiple times while a key is pressed. If you check again, the keydown event above returns empty while the `keyDownTimeout ` is already defined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe using the built-in volumeupbutton event will allow you to detect how long the click was, to determine if it should be treated as volume-up or skip-track. Instead you should be able to use the keyup/keydown events, combined with the keyCode property to determine if it is the volume button, like this:

```
const longPressTime = 1500;
let volumeUpButtonTimeout;
const volumeButtonKeyCode = 0; // you'll need to determine the key code

// cross platform way to get the key code
const getKeyCode = e => {
  if (e.key !== undefined) {
    return e.key;
  } else if (e.keyIdentifier !== undefined) {
    return e.keyIdentifier;
  } else if (e.keyCode !== undefined) {
    return e.keyCode;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (getKeyCode(e) == volumeButtonKeyCode) {
    volumeUpButtonTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // button was held for 1500ms, consider it a long-press
      // do long-press action
    }, longPressTime)
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if (getKeyCode(e) == volumeButtonKeyCode) {
    clearTimeout(volumeUpButtonTimeout);
  }
});
```

You could use this code to determine what keyCode corresponds to the volume up button:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: You're listening to `keyup` for both the cases, I think the first listener is for `keydown` and second thing, longPressTime is same for every case, so the setTimeout should be started for every callback and according to each keyCode, different action can be performed.

Comment: Also, `keyCode` is deprecated and not recommended. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the two keyup typos, I've fixed that. With my code I'm only checking for long-press against the volume button key code, so no need to track according to any other key code. The event.keyCode property is deprecated, but support of event.code isn't 100% there yet, so I added a function to fetch that code in a cross-platform way.