# Headphones prev/next button event detection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am wondering if there is an event or straightforward way to capture prev/next button on headphones other than `keydown/keyup` that has been mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467169/bluetooth-headphones-button-event-detection-in-javascript) which I find very hacky.

Something like:

```
document.on('next_track_event', e => {
    // next song was requested!
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is,

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() {
 // User hit "Previous Track" key. 
});
```

But it's experimental, so not sure about support

Here's a link to know more

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSession/setActionHandler