# Headphone buttons event detection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, bluetooth, dom-events, usb

I'm looking for a way to detect when a user press a button present on his headphones (bluetooth or not).

```
window.addEventListener('headphone_button_pressed', (e) => {
    // execute my code
})
```

For example, on my bluetooth headphones, there is 3 buttons: volume up, volume down and middle button to pause, hangup calls, answer calls, double tap to go next and triple to go back.
Is there is a way to detect theses buttons? like an EventListener.

For instance, these two answers : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467169/bluetooth-headphones-button-event-detection-in-javascript) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61685208/headphones-prev-next-button-event-detection-in-javascript) does not resolve my problem because they just doesn't work.
I also tried to connect my device with the [WebUsb API from Chrome](https://web.dev/usb/) but it doesn't work too because it is only made for specific devices ([see here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/LZXocaeCwDw/m/GLfAffGLAAAJ)).

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but it might be a start: https://web.dev/bluetooth/. Apparently there's a whole Bluetooth-oriented browser API `navigator.bluetooth`. That's presuming you're doing something in a browser, not with Node.js.

Comment: Thank for your answer! Yes, I'm doing everything in a browser. With Node.js the solution would be a lot more simplier.